# Please explain the meaning of <& in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Can you explain what this script means?

> 2<<< hello <&2 cat

If I run this shell script, it spits hello. But cannot understand what it means.

Can you please explain one by one?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why would someone do this? I'm having a hard time imagining a useful case that couldn't be more simply achieved in a more readable way...like maybe `echo hello`. Is this just a thought exercise in redirections? If it's just a learning exercise then it's a pretty good one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html 3.6.7 and 3.6.8

1. `2<<< hello` puts a string `hello` to stderr;
2. `<&2` redirect stderr to stdin
3. `cat` is a program which receive the string `hello` from stdin and print out

Comment: Good explanation, but there is no `cat` in the OP's code.

Comment: @user1934428 `cat` is there, but it's at the end. Redirects don't have to be after the command.

Comment: Ah, now I see it!